# Expand emmet autocompletes to multiple lines in sublime text

Tags: html, sublimetext2, emmet

When I type the following in sublime text 2 with emmet:

```
.one>label{foo}+input:r
```

I get one long line of code

```
<div class="one"><label for="">foo</label><input type="radio" name="" id=""></div>
```

is there any way to get emmet/sublime to output this style instead?

```
<div class="one">
    <label for="">foo</label>
    <input type="radio" name="" id="">
</div>
```

I tried playing around with the snippets.json with no success

Comment: Make sure you’ve set your syntax to HTML or XML or didn’t override default output profile for HTML.

Comment: Switching syntax to xml solves the issue (HTML doesn't), I think it may possibly html(liquid) syntax that causes the issue, thanks

Comment: HTML (Liquid)is not the same as HTML: it has different scope so Emmet thinks you’re using it in unknown syntax, most likely inside strings of programming languages. This is why it produces single-line output

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create `Packages/User/Emmet.sublime-settings` with the content of

```
{
    // Output profiles for syntaxes
    // http://docs.emmet.io/customization/syntax-profiles/
    "syntaxProfiles": {
        "html": {
            "tag_nl": true
            // "tag_nl_leaf": true
        }
    }
}
```

And check the [documentation](http://docs.emmet.io/customization/syntax-profiles/) for more information about `tag_nl`, `tag_nl_leaf` and other options.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably not the best answer but what I do is have reindent bound to a key and just hit that after.

In Preferences - Keybindings-User put something like

```
{ "keys": ["f12"], "command": "reindent"}
```

However im sure there is a way to do this properly