# Emmet expression expanded to single line

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, emmet, react-tsx

I'm learning to use [Emmet](https://emmet.io/) with Visual Studio Code in TypeScript React files `*.tsx`.

When I type `div.buttons>button.something+button.something-else` and hit TAB, it is expanded to the following:

```
<div className="buttons"><button className="something"></button><button className="something-else"></button></div>
```

However, if I type `.outer>.inner>h1+p` and hit TAB, it is expanded like this:

```
<div className="outer">
  <div className="inner">
    <h1></h1>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I have two questions:

1. What determines if some expression will be expanded to a single line or to one line per tag?
2. Can I force the first expression to expand to one line per tag?

Like this:

```
<div className="buttons">
  <button className="something"></button>
  <button className="something-else"></button>
</div>
```

---

### EDIT:

I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775954/expand-emmet-autocompletes-to-multiple-lines-in-sublime-text?rq=1), and I added the following setting to the Visual Studio Code user settings file, but nothing changed:

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "html": {
        "tag_nl": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

After playing with [the documentation](https://docs.emmet.io/customization/syntax-profiles/) I have found a solution to make it work as I want. You have to include this in the Visual Studio Code's user settings file:

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "jsx": {
        "inline_break": 1
    }
```

It forces a new line for each tag.

Bizarrely, setting `tag_nl` to `true` didn't produce any effect.